# (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) and (nonatomic, strong) in Objective-C ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

Any difference?

Suppose they are the same as in ARC, retain should be replaced by strong?

So can I say that they are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference. In accordance to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162926/ios-property-declaration-clarification/9163058#9163058):

> - `retain / strong`: (automatically retains / releases values on set, makes sure values do not deallocate unexpectedly) (default if ARC and object type)

Also, readwrite is the default for a property, so that isn't necessary, and you are already specifying `nonatomic`.

Answer (score 0):

strong replaces retain and functions similar. if its an object weak replaces assign(saying reference the object but do not incrment its reference count), nonatomic is the same between the two